# How to fetch a single record of a field from a document in MongoDb using Java(with the help of query not Loop)

Tags: java, database, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation

```
{
"_id" : "0289f117-54b7-451c-915c-c7948dbad22c",
"approvers" : [],
"reviewers" : [],
"cvoReviewers" : [],
"payer" : "medicaid",
"affiliationChildren" : [ 
    {
        "parentProviderEmailId" : "wy.providers+g51@gmail.com",
        "provider" : {
            "email" : "wy.providers+si5@gmail.com",
            "firstName" : "si5",
            "lastName" : "ind",
            "providerId" : "628b7425d442284ba6c5d330",
            "providerExternalId" : "65",
            "portalType" : "PE_ADMIN",
            "requestType" : "individual"
        },
        "providerDataId" : "78afa05a-a333-4633-8f17-c2b74a9e8ba6",
        "mapping" : {
            "lastName" : "ind",
            "specialty" : "Waiver",
            "primaryServiceAddress1" : "{\"line1\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"streetNumber\":\"5050\",\"streetName\":\"Powderhouse Rd\",\"city\":\"Cheyenne\",\"state\":\"WY\",\"zipCode\":\"82009\",\"zipExtension\":\"4800\",\"county\":\"Laramie\",\"latitude\":41.16474,\"longitude\":-104.80925,\"countyCode\":\"56021\",\"text\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"verified\":true,\"zipPlusFour\":\"82009-4800\"}",
            "newPatient" : "false",
            "gender" : "Male",
            "provider_address" : "{\"line1\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"streetNumber\":\"5050\",\"streetName\":\"Powderhouse Rd\",\"city\":\"Cheyenne\",\"state\":\"WY\",\"zipCode\":\"82009\",\"zipExtension\":\"4800\",\"county\":\"Laramie\",\"latitude\":41.16474,\"longitude\":-104.80925,\"countyCode\":\"56021\",\"text\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"verified\":true,\"zipPlusFour\":\"82009-4800\"}",
            "application_contact_email" : "wy.providers+si5@gmail.com",
            "taxonomyDescription" : [ 
                "Long Term Waiver"
            ],
            "primaryServiceState" : "Wyoming",
            "ssn" : "527-82-9927",
            "summaryFirstName" : "si5",
            "taxonomyId" : [ 
                "251B00000X"
            ],
            "primaryServiceFirstName" : "si5",
            "riskLevelBasedOnScreeningScore" : "Low",
            "signTitle" : "ind",
            "mailingState" : "Wyoming",
            "primaryServiceCountyCode" : "56021",
            "primaryServiceCity" : "Cheyenne",
            "primaryServicePhone" : "(456)456-4562",
            "providerName" : "si5",
            "primaryServiceZip" : "82009-4800",
            "primaryServiceMiddleName" : "",
            "zip" : "82009-4800",
            "providerFullName" : "si5 ind",
            "primaryServiceLastName" : "ind",
            "primaryServiceEmail" : "wy.providers+si5@gmail.com",
            "mailingCity" : "Cheyenne",
            "summaryLastName" : "ind",
            "isSummaryCheckbox" : true,
            "dob" : "05/01/2022",
            "mailingCountyCode" : "56021",
            "sftpFlag" : "Y"
        },
        "effectiveDateStart" : ISODate("2022-06-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "effectiveDateEnd" : ISODate("2022-11-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "type" : "GROUP_TO_INDIVIDUAL",
        "status" : "SIGNED",
        "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2022-06-07T04:47:13.924Z"),
        "reValidationDate" : ISODate("2023-05-24T00:00:00.728Z"),
        "createdDate" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:12:57.705Z"),
        "serviceLocations" : {
            "primary" : {
                "addressLine1" : "5050 Powderhouse Rd",
                "addressLine2" : "",
                "city" : "Cheyenne",
                "state" : "WY",
                "zip" : "82009",
                "countyCode" : "56021",
                "county" : "Laramie",
                "addedDate" : "2022-06-07T10:17:24+05:30"
            }
        },
        "isAutoAffiliated" : false,
        "_class" : "com.hhstechgroup.hummingbird.models.ProviderAffiliation"
    }, 
    {
        "parentProviderEmailId" : "wy.providers+g51@gmail.com",
        "provider" : {
            "email" : "wy.providers+si6@gmail.com",
            "firstName" : "si6",
            "lastName" : "ind",
            "providerId" : "628b7780d442284ba6c5d337",
            "providerExternalId" : "66",
            "portalType" : "PE_ADMIN",
            "requestType" : "individual"
        },
        "providerDataId" : "41925991-e440-4c81-a232-31c63c94c9ee",
        "mapping" : {
            "lastName" : "ind",
            "specialty" : "Waiver",
            "primaryServiceAddress1" : "{\"line1\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"streetNumber\":\"5050\",\"streetName\":\"Powderhouse Rd\",\"city\":\"Cheyenne\",\"state\":\"WY\",\"zipCode\":\"82009\",\"zipExtension\":\"4800\",\"county\":\"Laramie\",\"latitude\":41.16474,\"longitude\":-104.80925,\"countyCode\":\"56021\",\"text\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"verified\":true,\"zipPlusFour\":\"82009-4800\"}",
            "newPatient" : "false",
            "gender" : "Male",
            "provider_address" : "{\"line1\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"streetNumber\":\"5050\",\"streetName\":\"Powderhouse Rd\",\"city\":\"Cheyenne\",\"state\":\"WY\",\"zipCode\":\"82009\",\"zipExtension\":\"4800\",\"county\":\"Laramie\",\"latitude\":41.16474,\"longitude\":-104.80925,\"countyCode\":\"56021\",\"text\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"verified\":true,\"zipPlusFour\":\"82009-4800\"}",
            "application_contact_email" : "wy.providers+si6@gmail.com",
            "taxonomyDescription" : [ 
                "Long Term Waiver"
            ],
            "primaryServiceState" : "Wyoming",
            "ssn" : "562-87-1998",
            "summaryFirstName" : "si6",
            "taxonomyId" : [ 
                "251B00000X"
            ],
            "primaryServiceFirstName" : "si6",
            "riskLevelBasedOnScreeningScore" : "Low",
            "signTitle" : "inds",
            "mailingState" : "Wyoming",
            "primaryServiceCountyCode" : "56021",
            "primaryServiceCity" : "Cheyenne",
            "primaryServicePhone" : "(527)290-9298",
            "providerName" : "si6",
            "primaryServiceZip" : "82009-4800",
            "primaryServiceMiddleName" : "",
            "zip" : "82009-4800",
            "providerFullName" : "si6 ind",
            "primaryServiceLastName" : "ind",
            "primaryServiceEmail" : "wy.providers+si6@gmail.com",
            "mailingCity" : "Cheyenne",
            "summaryLastName" : "ind",
            "isSummaryCheckbox" : true,
            "dob" : "05/01/2022",
            "mailingCountyCode" : "56021",
            "sftpFlag" : "Y"
        },
        "effectiveDateStart" : ISODate("2022-06-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "effectiveDateEnd" : ISODate("2022-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "type" : "GROUP_TO_INDIVIDUAL",
        "status" : "SIGNED",
        "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2022-06-07T04:47:37.828Z"),
        "reValidationDate" : ISODate("2023-05-24T00:00:00.696Z"),
        "createdDate" : ISODate("2022-05-24T10:13:20.687Z"),
        "serviceLocations" : {
            "primary" : {
                "addressLine1" : "5050 Powderhouse Rd",
                "addressLine2" : "",
                "city" : "Cheyenne",
                "state" : "WY",
                "zip" : "82009",
                "countyCode" : "56021",
                "county" : "Laramie",
                "addedDate" : "2022-06-07T10:17:49+05:30"
            }
        },
        "isAutoAffiliated" : false,
        "_class" : "com.hhstechgroup.hummingbird.models.ProviderAffiliation"
    }, 
    {
        "parentProviderEmailId" : "wy.providers+g51@gmail.com",
        "provider" : {
            "email" : "wy.providers+si7@gmail.com",
            "firstName" : "si7",
            "lastName" : "ind",
            "providerId" : "628b794fb410d05f04afaa14",
            "providerExternalId" : "67",
            "portalType" : "PE_ADMIN",
            "requestType" : "individual"
        },
        "providerDataId" : "a1b0d430-56f1-4c20-821b-3ef168704ea3",
        "mapping" : {
            "lastName" : "ind",
            "specialty" : "Waiver",
            "primaryServiceAddress1" : "{\"line1\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"streetNumber\":\"5050\",\"streetName\":\"Powderhouse Rd\",\"city\":\"Cheyenne\",\"state\":\"WY\",\"zipCode\":\"82009\",\"zipExtension\":\"4800\",\"county\":\"Laramie\",\"latitude\":41.16474,\"longitude\":-104.80925,\"countyCode\":\"56021\",\"text\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"verified\":true,\"zipPlusFour\":\"82009-4800\"}",
            "newPatient" : "false",
            "gender" : "Male",
            "provider_address" : "{\"line1\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"streetNumber\":\"5050\",\"streetName\":\"Powderhouse Rd\",\"city\":\"Cheyenne\",\"state\":\"WY\",\"zipCode\":\"82009\",\"zipExtension\":\"4800\",\"county\":\"Laramie\",\"latitude\":41.16474,\"longitude\":-104.80925,\"countyCode\":\"56021\",\"text\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"verified\":true,\"zipPlusFour\":\"82009-4800\"}",
            "application_contact_email" : "wy.providers+si7@gmail.com",
            "taxonomyDescription" : [ 
                "Long Term Waiver"
            ],
            "primaryServiceState" : "Wyoming",
            "ssn" : "452-64-5277",
            "summaryFirstName" : "si7",
            "taxonomyId" : [ 
                "251B00000X"
            ],
            "primaryServiceFirstName" : "si7",
            "riskLevelBasedOnScreeningScore" : "Low",
            "signTitle" : "ind",
            "mailingState" : "Wyoming",
            "primaryServiceCity" : "Cheyenne",
            "primaryServiceCountyCode" : "56021",
            "primaryServicePhone" : "(672)399-3793",
            "providerName" : "si7",
            "primaryServiceZip" : "82009-4800",
            "zip" : "82009-4800",
            "providerFullName" : "si7 ind",
            "primaryServiceLastName" : "ind",
            "primaryServiceEmail" : "wy.providers+si7@gmail.com",
            "mailingCity" : "Cheyenne",
            "summaryLastName" : "ind",
            "isSummaryCheckbox" : true,
            "dob" : "05/01/2022",
            "mailingCountyCode" : "56021",
            "sftpFlag" : "Y"
        },
        "effectiveDateStart" : ISODate("2022-06-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "effectiveDateEnd" : ISODate("2022-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "type" : "GROUP_TO_INDIVIDUAL",
        "status" : "SIGNED",
        "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2022-06-07T04:47:57.300Z"),
        "reValidationDate" : ISODate("2023-05-24T00:00:00.544Z"),
        "createdDate" : ISODate("2022-05-24T12:34:04.446Z"),
        "serviceLocations" : {
            "primary" : {
                "addressLine1" : "5050 Powderhouse Rd",
                "addressLine2" : "",
                "city" : "Cheyenne",
                "state" : "WY",
                "zip" : "82009",
                "countyCode" : "56021",
                "county" : "Laramie",
                "addedDate" : "2022-06-07T10:18:08+05:30"
            }
        },
        "isAutoAffiliated" : false,
        "_class" : "com.hhstechgroup.hummingbird.models.ProviderAffiliation"
    }, 
    {
        "parentProviderEmailId" : "wy.providers+g51@gmail.com",
        "provider" : {
            "email" : "wy.providers+p50@gmail.com",
            "firstName" : "P50",
            "lastName" : "Pem",
            "providerId" : "629ed1bacbc3d9017b9d7dc2",
            "providerExternalId" : "126",
            "portalType" : "PE_ADMIN",
            "requestType" : "PEM"
        },
        "providerDataId" : "be24cad8-5171-4c8c-bc5a-b22a6d896ff7",
        "mapping" : {
            "website_address" : "",
            "zip" : "82009-4800",
            "lastName" : "Pem",
            "providerFullName" : "P50 Pem",
            "newPatient" : "false",
            "gender" : "Male",
            "provider_address" : "{\"line1\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"streetNumber\":\"5050\",\"streetName\":\"Powderhouse Rd\",\"city\":\"Cheyenne\",\"state\":\"WY\",\"zipCode\":\"82009\",\"zipExtension\":\"4800\",\"county\":\"Laramie\",\"latitude\":41.16474,\"longitude\":-104.80925,\"countyCode\":\"56021\",\"text\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"verified\":true,\"zipPlusFour\":\"82009-4800\"}",
            "mailingCity" : "Cheyenne",
            "application_contact_email" : "wy.providers+p50@gmail.com",
            "mailingState" : "Wyoming",
            "sftpFlag" : "N",
            "providerName" : "P50"
        },
        "effectiveDateStart" : ISODate("2022-06-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "effectiveDateEnd" : ISODate("2022-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "type" : "GROUP_TO_PEM",
        "status" : "SIGNED",
        "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2022-06-07T04:48:21.781Z"),
        "reValidationDate" : ISODate("2023-06-07T00:00:00.454Z"),
        "createdDate" : ISODate("2022-06-07T04:41:43.451Z"),
        "serviceLocations" : {
            "primary" : {
                "addressLine1" : "5050 Powderhouse Rd",
                "addressLine2" : "",
                "city" : "Cheyenne",
                "state" : "WY",
                "zip" : "82009",
                "countyCode" : "56021",
                "county" : "Laramie",
                "addedDate" : "2022-06-07T10:18:32+05:30"
            }
        },
        "isAutoAffiliated" : false,
        "_class" : "com.hhstechgroup.hummingbird.models.ProviderAffiliation"
    }, 
    {
        "parentProviderEmailId" : "wy.providers+g51@gmail.com",
        "provider" : {
            "email" : "wy.providers+p51@gmail.com",
            "firstName" : "P51",
            "lastName" : "Pem",
            "providerId" : "629ed2efcbc3d9017b9d7dc9",
            "providerExternalId" : "128",
            "portalType" : "PE_ADMIN",
            "requestType" : "PEM"
        },
        "providerDataId" : "c0d79d06-d8ec-4723-bc72-c8016a0922d0",
        "mapping" : {
            "zip" : "82009-4800",
            "lastName" : "Pem",
            "providerFullName" : "p51 Pem",
            "newPatient" : "false",
            "gender" : "Male",
            "provider_address" : "{\"line1\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"streetNumber\":\"5050\",\"streetName\":\"Powderhouse Rd\",\"city\":\"Cheyenne\",\"state\":\"WY\",\"zipCode\":\"82009\",\"zipExtension\":\"4800\",\"county\":\"Laramie\",\"latitude\":41.16474,\"longitude\":-104.80925,\"countyCode\":\"56021\",\"text\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"verified\":true,\"zipPlusFour\":\"82009-4800\"}",
            "mailingCity" : "Cheyenne",
            "application_contact_email" : "wy.providers+p51@gmail.com",
            "mailingState" : "Wyoming",
            "sftpFlag" : "N",
            "providerName" : "p51"
        },
        "effectiveDateStart" : ISODate("2022-06-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "effectiveDateEnd" : ISODate("2022-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "type" : "GROUP_TO_PEM",
        "status" : "SIGNED",
        "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2022-06-07T04:48:45.614Z"),
        "reValidationDate" : ISODate("2023-06-07T00:00:00.435Z"),
        "createdDate" : ISODate("2022-06-07T04:42:11.431Z"),
        "serviceLocations" : {
            "primary" : {
                "addressLine1" : "5050 Powderhouse Rd",
                "addressLine2" : "",
                "city" : "Cheyenne",
                "state" : "WY",
                "zip" : "82009",
                "countyCode" : "56021",
                "county" : "Laramie",
                "addedDate" : "2022-06-07T10:18:45+05:30"
            }
        },
        "isAutoAffiliated" : false,
        "_class" : "com.hhstechgroup.hummingbird.models.ProviderAffiliation"
    }
],
"affiliationParents" : [],
"taxonomyDetails" : {},
"children" : [ 
    {
        "$ref" : "runtimeSections",
        "$id" : "ecf92055-7ebb-4a76-bdc8-3fbf809336bf"
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "runtimeSections",
        "$id" : "1fab57a2-e759-4e3e-896f-0dfb4668b712"
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "runtimeSections",
        "$id" : "fe15668c-ec7b-423b-af1e-8e3e1d2307f2"
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "runtimeSections",
        "$id" : "f20c6a20-75e0-4fea-b327-5aa20ecb34ac"
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "runtimeSections",
        "$id" : "fc8eee6c-1a71-437d-8898-d3835e990042"
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "runtimeSections",
        "$id" : "083ac588-c349-41c9-b045-0140b2fda9cd"
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "runtimeSections",
        "$id" : "8e309413-6f38-435d-9dad-2f48d2a7c307"
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "runtimeSections",
        "$id" : "7cd3d254-c199-4bcd-b650-a4c93b07fcf3"
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "runtimeSections",
        "$id" : "41fb42b1-294f-4812-bd33-ebae6bfe762f"
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "runtimeSections",
        "$id" : "753e53bd-0c5e-4bf4-a11d-575f51284cca"
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "runtimeSections",
        "$id" : "670bba3a-ef6f-4e56-a3db-00f002781216"
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "runtimeSections",
        "$id" : "d1c6372c-905b-4551-80cd-efc96ab039cd"
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "runtimeSections",
        "$id" : "71a3eda4-798a-4310-8fe2-eb5a3d6844ea"
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "runtimeSections",
        "$id" : "26f0f9c0-359d-490d-8c2d-f3e1da57c8b5"
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "runtimeSections",
        "$id" : "f8687f54-233d-4dd5-a6b9-44734cd78177"
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "runtimeSections",
        "$id" : "89b5371d-bd24-4687-a6f3-470fe6055942"
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "runtimeSections",
        "$id" : "4fa3a7a0-15d4-472c-98b3-251da1d5ba38"
    }, 
    {
        "$ref" : "runtimeSections",
        "$id" : "6841928e-3568-41b9-be3f-a8ecd6f89d74"
    }
],
"author" : {
    "email" : "wy.providers+g51@gmail.com",
    "firstName" : "g51",
    "lastName" : "group",
    "providerId" : "629ed151cbc3d9017b9d7dbf",
    "providerExternalId" : "125",
    "portalType" : "PE_ADMIN",
    "requestType" : "group"
},
"requestId" : NumberLong(247),
"requestType" : "group",
"status" : {
    "pe" : "APPROVED",
    "iu" : "APPROVED",
    "notes" : "",
    "priority" : 16,
    "rank" : "",
    "screeningScore" : "98",
    "screeningDate" : ISODate("2022-06-07T04:45:26.017Z"),
    "screeningNote" : "",
    "screeningReason" : "",
    "scheduleDate" : "06/07/2022",
    "scheduleReason" : "",
    "retroActive" : "false",
    "effectiveDate" : "2022-06-07",
    "apvReason" : "Positive results ",
    "statusChangedBy" : "internal.user.dyp+cd@gmail.com",
    "futureActive" : false,
    "_class" : "com.hhstechgroup.hummingbird.models.runtime.RequestStatus"
},
"createdDate" : ISODate("2022-06-07T04:18:44.221Z"),
"lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2022-06-07T04:49:03.149Z"),
"submittedDate" : ISODate("2022-06-07T04:22:11.104Z"),
"statusChangedDate" : ISODate("2022-06-07T04:49:01.712Z"),
"deleted" : false,
"metadata" : {
    "READY_FOR_SIGN_AGREEMENT_TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2022-06-07T04:21:23.717Z"),
    "AGGREMENT_PDF_ID" : "26318031da0390ea91f151f23d5523e1",
    "APPLICATION_AGREEMENT_PDF_ID" : "26318031da0390ea91f151f23d553499",
    "isAggrementSigned" : "true",
    "READY_FOR_SIGN_TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2022-06-07T04:21:36.902Z"),
    "APPLICATION_ORIGINAL_PDF_ID" : "b37a296c204ee237655477a40f4ea741",
    "signUpRequest" : {
        "clientId" : "95c647d0be93e5deee5a8a44ecb97730",
        "signatureRequestId" : "edb1b6f08b0ecc25ac04b120ca4ca3a45b131b06",
        "signUrl" : "https://app.hellosign.com/editor/embeddedSign?signature_id=735345253d7d4689831b3c8181a49ee4&token=71fa1da4b91634c53911da1efa896eba",
        "_class" : "com.hhstechgroup.hummingbird.models.SignUpRequest"
    },
    "APPLICATION_PDF_ID" : "26318031da0390ea91f151f23d558f55",
    "SIGNED_USERS" : [ 
        "wy.providers+g51@gmail.com"
    ]
},
"customSettings" : {
    "Payment" : true,
    "Provider_Agreement" : true,
    "Sections" : true,
    "Summary" : true,
    "Secondary_Service_Location" : true,
    "HelloSign" : true,
    "Affiliation" : true
},
"mapping" : {
    "groupName" : "g51 group",
    "newPatient" : "false",
    "providerFullName" : "g51 group",
    "fein" : "78-9320938",
    "mailingState" : "Wyoming",
    "mailingCity" : "Cheyenne",
    "zip" : "82009-4800",
    "provider_address" : "{\"line1\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"streetNumber\":\"5050\",\"streetName\":\"Powderhouse Rd\",\"city\":\"Cheyenne\",\"state\":\"WY\",\"zipCode\":\"82009\",\"zipExtension\":\"4800\",\"county\":\"Laramie\",\"latitude\":41.16474,\"longitude\":-104.80925,\"countyCode\":\"56021\",\"text\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"verified\":true,\"zipPlusFour\":\"82009-4800\"}",
    "mailingCountyCode" : "56021",
    "specialty" : "Audiology",
    "taxonomyDescription" : [ 
        "Audiologist"
    ],
    "taxonomyId" : [ 
        "231H00000X"
    ],
    "primaryServiceCity" : "Cheyenne",
    "primaryServiceCountyCode" : "56021",
    "primaryServiceAddress1" : "{\"line1\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"streetNumber\":\"5050\",\"streetName\":\"Powderhouse Rd\",\"city\":\"Cheyenne\",\"state\":\"WY\",\"zipCode\":\"82009\",\"zipExtension\":\"4800\",\"county\":\"Laramie\",\"latitude\":41.16474,\"longitude\":-104.80925,\"countyCode\":\"56021\",\"text\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"verified\":true,\"zipPlusFour\":\"82009-4800\"}",
    "primaryServiceState" : "Wyoming",
    "primaryServiceZip" : "82009-4800",
    "primaryServiceFirstName" : "g51",
    "primaryServiceMiddleName" : "",
    "primaryServiceLastName" : "group",
    "primaryServicePhone" : "(893)092-0928",
    "primaryServiceEmail" : "wy.providers+g51@gmail.com",
    "signTitle" : "group",
    "sftpFlag" : "Y",
    "riskLevelBasedOnScreeningScore" : "Low"
},
"sync" : {},
"assigneeHistory" : [],
"sslDeletedHistoryList" : [],
"changed" : "",
"count" : 0,
"affiliationCount" : 0,
"pendingDays" : NumberLong(0),
"templateId" : "provider_group",
"_class" : "com.hhstechgroup.hummingbird.models.Request",
"assignedBy" : "statusScheduler",
"assignedDate" : ISODate("2022-06-07T04:45:42.711Z"),
"assignee" : {
    "email" : "internal.user.dyp+cd@gmail.com",
    "firstName" : "Cindy",
    "lastName" : "Duran",
    "providerId" : "627bae1e51a23b326dcadeb4",
    "portalType" : "IU",
    "_class" : "com.hhstechgroup.hummingbird.models.UserVM"
}
```

}

**I want to fetch a single record from "affiliationChildren" property of this document where "provider.email" is "wy.providers+si5@gmail.com". Need to fetch without using loop, can resolve using aggregation, Projections etc.
Currently affiliation children set contains 5 records, I want to fetch only 1 record on the basis of provider.email property.
The expected result will be:**

```
{
        "parentProviderEmailId" : "wy.providers+g51@gmail.com",
        "provider" : {
            "email" : "wy.providers+si5@gmail.com",
            "firstName" : "si5",
            "lastName" : "ind",
            "providerId" : "628b7425d442284ba6c5d330",
            "providerExternalId" : "65",
            "portalType" : "PE_ADMIN",
            "requestType" : "individual"
        },
        "providerDataId" : "78afa05a-a333-4633-8f17-c2b74a9e8ba6",
        "mapping" : {
            "lastName" : "ind",
            "specialty" : "Waiver",
            "primaryServiceAddress1" : "{\"line1\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"streetNumber\":\"5050\",\"streetName\":\"Powderhouse Rd\",\"city\":\"Cheyenne\",\"state\":\"WY\",\"zipCode\":\"82009\",\"zipExtension\":\"4800\",\"county\":\"Laramie\",\"latitude\":41.16474,\"longitude\":-104.80925,\"countyCode\":\"56021\",\"text\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"verified\":true,\"zipPlusFour\":\"82009-4800\"}",
            "newPatient" : "false",
            "gender" : "Male",
            "provider_address" : "{\"line1\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"streetNumber\":\"5050\",\"streetName\":\"Powderhouse Rd\",\"city\":\"Cheyenne\",\"state\":\"WY\",\"zipCode\":\"82009\",\"zipExtension\":\"4800\",\"county\":\"Laramie\",\"latitude\":41.16474,\"longitude\":-104.80925,\"countyCode\":\"56021\",\"text\":\"5050 Powderhouse Rd\",\"verified\":true,\"zipPlusFour\":\"82009-4800\"}",
            "application_contact_email" : "wy.providers+si5@gmail.com",
            "taxonomyDescription" : [ 
                "Long Term Waiver"
            ],
            "primaryServiceState" : "Wyoming",
            "ssn" : "527-82-9927",
            "summaryFirstName" : "si5",
            "taxonomyId" : [ 
                "251B00000X"
            ],
            "primaryServiceFirstName" : "si5",
            "riskLevelBasedOnScreeningScore" : "Low",
            "signTitle" : "ind",
            "mailingState" : "Wyoming",
            "primaryServiceCountyCode" : "56021",
            "primaryServiceCity" : "Cheyenne",
            "primaryServicePhone" : "(456)456-4562",
            "providerName" : "si5",
            "primaryServiceZip" : "82009-4800",
            "primaryServiceMiddleName" : "",
            "zip" : "82009-4800",
            "providerFullName" : "si5 ind",
            "primaryServiceLastName" : "ind",
            "primaryServiceEmail" : "wy.providers+si5@gmail.com",
            "mailingCity" : "Cheyenne",
            "summaryLastName" : "ind",
            "isSummaryCheckbox" : true,
            "dob" : "05/01/2022",
            "mailingCountyCode" : "56021",
            "sftpFlag" : "Y"
        },
        "effectiveDateStart" : ISODate("2022-06-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "effectiveDateEnd" : ISODate("2022-11-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "type" : "GROUP_TO_INDIVIDUAL",
        "status" : "SIGNED",
        "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2022-06-07T04:47:13.924Z"),
        "reValidationDate" : ISODate("2023-05-24T00:00:00.728Z"),
        "createdDate" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:12:57.705Z"),
        "serviceLocations" : {
            "primary" : {
                "addressLine1" : "5050 Powderhouse Rd",
                "addressLine2" : "",
                "city" : "Cheyenne",
                "state" : "WY",
                "zip" : "82009",
                "countyCode" : "56021",
                "county" : "Laramie",
                "addedDate" : "2022-06-07T10:17:24+05:30"
            }
        },
        "isAutoAffiliated" : false,
        "_class" : "com.hhstechgroup.hummingbird.models.ProviderAffiliation"
    }
```

Comment: You can use an aggregation with `$filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I trying to resolve my issue, finally got the solution
with this query I got my expected result.

I already had a set of entities id which I am travrsing as entityId. with the help of entityid fetched the main document and with the aggregation query got the affiliationchildren andfrom affiliationChildren now I am fetching 2 objects of affiliationChildren with provided emailIds = individualEmail,pemAffiliationEmail.

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("_id").is(entityId);
        criteria.and("affiliationChildren.provider.email").in(Arrays.asList(individualEmail,pemAffiliationEmail));
        GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group("_id", "requestType").push(AFFILIATION_CHILDREN).as(AFFILIATION_CHILDREN);
        Aggregation aggregation = null;
            aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                    unwind("affiliationChildren"),
                    match(criteria),
                    groupOperation
            );
        final AggregationResults<ProviderData> aggregateResult = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, PROVIDERS_DATA, ProviderData.class);
        providerDataList = aggregateResult.getMappedResults();
```

Comment: The bold text is glaring, difficult to read. Please take a moment to edit it yourself or approve one of the suggested edits.

Comment: The bold text is glaring, difficult to read. Please take a moment to edit it yourself or approve one of the suggested edits.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      affiliationChildren: {
        $elemMatch: {
          "provider.email": "wy.providers+si5@gmail.com"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      affiliationChildren: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$affiliationChildren",
          as: "children",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$children.provider.email",
              "wy.providers+si5@gmail.com"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$affiliationChildren"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$affiliationChildren"
    }
  }
])
```

Here's the playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oaaRKNDc-EY).

This is the java equivalent of the above query:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.mongodb.client.AggregateIterable;
import org.bson.Document;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(
                new MongoClientURI(
                        "mongodb://localhost:27017/"
                )
        );
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("StackOverflow");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("sample");

        AggregateIterable<Document> result = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(new Document("$match",
                        new Document("affiliationChildren",
                                new Document("$elemMatch",
                                        new Document("provider.email", "wy.providers+si5@gmail.com")))),
                new Document("$project",
                        new Document("affiliationChildren",
                                new Document("$filter",
                                        new Document("input", "$affiliationChildren")
                                                .append("as", "children")
                                                .append("cond",
                                                        new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$$children.provider.email", "wy.providers+si5@gmail.com")))))
                                .append("_id", 0L)),
                new Document("$unwind",
                        new Document("path", "$affiliationChildren")),
                new Document("$replaceRoot",
                        new Document("newRoot", "$affiliationChildren"))));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Charchit, Thanks for the mongo query  but I needed query in Java language

Comment: Hey Aman, updated the answer.